# Grab string until one two conditions

Tags: regex

Let's say I have the following two strings:

```
...some content above
Destination:        Fox - Man (200.170.217.200)
...some content below
```

And

```
...some content above
Destination:        Some content goes here and ends
...some content below
```

The regex should grab:

`Fox - Man` and `Some content goes here and ends`.

I would like to grab everything in the description except a trailing parenthetical. Basically, it is combining these two regexes:

```
Destination:\s*(.+\S)    # everything until the end of the line
Destination:\s*([^(]+\S) # everything until the first open parenthetical
```

How would I combine these so that the `exit at (` takes precedence? Sample here: https://regex101.com/r/5qUwRW/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
Destination:\s*([^(\n]+[^\s(])
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/OBxff1/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Destination:             'Destination:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^(\n]+                  any character except: '(', '\n'
                             (newline) (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\s(]                   any character except: whitespace (\n,
                             \r, \t, \f, and " "), '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Comment: Oh, nice I can just add `\n` to the negated group that makes it simple! `Destination:\s*([^(\n]+)\S` -- https://regex101.com/r/5qUwRW/2

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 This is to prevent matching a line feed.

Comment: oh I see yours also ignores whitespace before the parenthetical so was much better than what I just typed in -- thanks for your help.